# Trapezopid shaped face to square UV coordinates has unfavourable skewing

Tags: uv

When I map a trapezoid shaped face to square shaped uv coordinates it doesnt skew how I would expect it to. I want it to go to from fat to slim pixels. Instead it seems to skew based on triangles maybe?

(object scale is applied btw)

[image: UV skewing]

Comment: Yes, that is exactly correct.  If you manually triangulate that face and inspect the texture + viewport, I think it will make more sense that this is actually what it has to do.  There are different ways to map trapezoids to rectangles (perspective mapping does exactly that after all), but they have their own (significant!) drawbacks and aren't available in Blender.  Your only solutions are some combination of remap, make more verts to minimize the issue, and/or live with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a seam down one side and around the circumferences top and bottom, then you can:

- Align the approximately cylindrical region in an orthographic view (minus the caps)
- <kbd>U</kbd> unwrap the tube with 'Cylinder Projection'

[image]

Comment: I believe that only looks okay because of the vert density.  Take a look at https://pasteboard.co/JTFqeYg.png .  On the left, I have a simply subdivided copy to demonstrate how you get better mapping by using more verts, but the problem never actually goes away.  The real solution is, don't try to map trapezoids to quads; if you need your texture to shrink, change the texture.

Comment: @Nathan You're  right. Am I right with this reasoning? This answer kind of misses the point, that barycentric interpolation from the corners of  triangles will never match Cartesian interpolation along X and Y of a quad? This answer  just increases accuracy by increasing samples. Does linearly changing the texture actually help with that? (Besides all, you can always mark every edge as a seam, and just U unwrap, which projects down the normal of every face?)

Comment: The problem is that the per-sample texture coordinates are actually generated after the (invisible) triangulation of the mesh.  When we have UV distortion, that matters.  (Try triangulating the mesh in both ways and see how it changes the mapping.)  You can compensate for the distortion in the texture if you need to, but you won't end up with a square UV grid image.  Texture baking or texture painting are both methods that can be used to create textures that compensate for the distortion.  (In this case, consider baking the texture, selected-to-active, from the subdivided mesh.)

Comment: @Nathan Yes. So the problem is the UV -> shaded surface interpolation, not the Geometry -> UV mapping.